# Something keeps opening Outlook

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook-2010, malware

I have an interesting little icon in my taskbar that, when hovered over tells me that "Another program is using Outlook". This is very interesting, as I have not intentionally installed anything that should be doing that.

Outlook.exe stays open for five seconds, terminates, and opens again four seconds later. I don't actually use Outlook, thankfully, so it can't actually do anything, but it looks to me like I have a worm on my system that is trying to mail itself. Malwarebytes Anti-Malware and Spybot S&D don't report any infections, though, so I'm not sure.

What could be causing this other than a malicious program? Is there any way to figure out what requested that Outlook open? The parent of OUTLOOK.EXE is a svchost.exe instance that provides the following services:

```
BrokerInfrastructure, Background Tasks Infrastructure Service
DcomLaunch, DCOM Server Process Launcher
LSM, Local Session Manager
PlugPlay, Plug and Play
Power, Power
```

The first two are presumably the reason this process is the one that is opening Outlook.

Comment: Seems to me that there ought to be a better way to diagnose a problem than killing processes randomly until it stops :P. To re-state, there are no programs on my computer that I know of that seem like they should have any legitimate reason to talk to Outlook. Much less to restart it every four seconds.

Comment: I wonder if process monitor will help (you'll have to Google for it as software recommendations are off topic here)

Comment: @DaveRook We can recommend software as a solution (just not "link-only" answers), Folks just can't ASK for software recommendations. :)

Comment: The process of elimination is the best way to find the culprit process.  Now there are smart ways to perform that process.  If a minimal start-up does not introduce this behavior you know its one of those start-up processes and can using your head decide what is a possible culprit.